# Creating dictionary from a '.fasta' file containing several genes from an organism

Tags: dictionary

I have a '.txt' file in which a list of genes are given and their sequence. I need to create a dictionary in which the keys are the names of the genes and the values are the sequences.

I want the output of the dictionary to be this:
dict = ('sequence1' : 'AATTGGCC', 'sequence2' : 'AAGGCCTT', ...)

So this is what I tried, but I ran into some problems:

```
dictionary = {}

accesion_number = ""
sequentie = ""

with open("6EP.fasta", "r") as proteoom:
    for line in proteoom:
        if line.startswith(">"):
            line.strip()
            dictionary[accesion_number] = sequentie
            sequentie = ""
        else:
            sequentie = sequentie + line.rstrip().strip("\n").strip("\r")
    dictionary[accesion_number] = sequentie
```

Does anyone know what went wrong here, and how I can fix it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: How you edit and run your code should have no affect on the output.  Importing from the standard library is part of 'vanilla' python, though I don't know that any stdlib modules are relevant here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two ways to do this:

### High memory usage

If the file is not too large, you can use `readlines()` and then use the indexes like so:

```
IDs = []
sequences = []

with open('Proteome.fasta', 'r') as f:
    raw_data = f.readlines()

for i, l in enumerate(raw_data):
    if l[0] == '>':
        IDs.append(l)
        sequences.append(raw_data[i + 1])
```

### Low memory usage

Now, if you don't want to load the contents of the file into memory, then I think you can read the file twice by saving the indexes of every ID line plus one, like so:

1. Get the `'>'` lines and their `indexes`, which will be the ID index plus one
2. Compare if the line number is in the `indexes` list and, if so, then append the content to your variable

In here, I'm taking advantage of the fact that the lists are, by definition, sorted.

```
IDs = []
indexes = []
sequences = []

with open('Proteome.fasta', 'r') as f:
    for i, l in enumerate(f):
        IDs.append(l)                  # Get your IDs
        indexes.append(i + 1)          # Get the index of the ID + 1

with open('Proteome.fasta', 'r') as f:
    for i, l in enumerate(f):
        if i == indexes[0]:            # Check whether line matches with the index
            sequences.append(l)        # Get your sequence
            indexes.pop(0)             # Remove the first element of the indexes
```

I hope this helps! ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

---

```
ids = []
seq = []
char = ['_', ':', '*', '#']                #invalid in sequence
seqs = ''

with open('fasta.txt', 'r') as f:          #open sample fasta
  for line in f:
    if line.startswith('>'):               
      ids.append(line.strip('\n'))
      if seqs != '':                       #if there's previous seq
        seq.append(seqs)                   #append the seq
        seqs = ''                          #then start a new seq
    elif line not in char:                
      seqs = seqs + line.strip('\n')       #build seq with each line until '>'
  seq.append(seqs)                         #append any remaining seq

print(ids)
print(seq)
```

**Result**

---

```
['>SeqABCD [organism=Mus musculus]', '>SeqABCDE [organism=Plasmodium]']
['ACGTCAGTCACGTACGTCAGTTCAGTC...', 'GGTACTGCAAAGTTCTTCCGCCTGATTA...']
```

**Sample File**

---

```
>SeqABCD [organism=Mus musculus]
ACGTCAGTCACGTACGTCAGTTCAGTCARYSTYSATCASMBMBDH
ATCGTTTTTATGTAATTGCTTATTGTTGTGTGTAGATTTTTTAA
AAATATCATTTGAGGTCAATACAAATCCTATTTCTATCGTTTTT
CCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAACCTCTGAATCCTTAAT
>SeqABCDE [organism=Plasmodium falciparum]
GGTACTGCAAAGTTCTTCCGCCTGATTAATTATCCATTTTACCTT
TTGTTTTGCTTCTTTGAAGTAGTTTCTCTTTGCAAAATTCCTCTT
GGTACTGCAAAGTTCTTCCGCCTGATTAATTATCCGGTACTGCAA
AGTCAATTTTATATAATTTAATCAAATAAATAAGTTTATGGTTAA
```